# How to accept string 'end' to finish program in a Vector using C++?

Tags: c++

So I declare an int variable called listOfItems that can accept input from the user.
Now that variable can be a big number but if the user decides to stop adding items into the vector(using the 'string value' var) he/she can easily stop by just typing 'end' into the program.

```
  // DECLARE INT listOfItems and shoppingList vector
  int listOfItems = 0;
  vector<string> shoppingList;
  cout << "Please enter the number of items you wish to purchase: " << endl;
  cout << "type end to finish program " << endl;

  cin >> listOfItems;
  /// SECOND VERSION AFTER READING SOME COMMENTS
  string value;
  do {
    cin >> value;
    shoppingList.push_back(value);  // add new value to vector
  } while(value != "end" && value != "END");


/// MAIN VERSION
for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems; i++) {
    string value;
    cin >> value;
    do {
      shoppingList.push_back(value);  // add new value to vector
    } while(value != "end" && value != "END");
  }
```

In the block above, I just create a for-loop that will run as many times as specified in the listOfItems submitted by the user. Inside said for-loop, I added a do while, that should add items into the vector as long as the string has not met the 'end' or 'END' keyword.

It is not working. Does anyone have any idea on fixing this?

Comment: What is the `do while` loop supposed to do? Can you explain your code out to us?

Comment: If you don't want end in the list, you should test the string for "end" before inserting it.

Comment: It's an infinite loop. Do-while will never be going to end. If your 1st entry is not 'END' it will enter do-while and continues to loop in do-while condition.

Comment: If you want to add strings until you find "end", you should ask the user for a string more than once.

Comment: Why two loops? I think you should sit down and talk the logic through with your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Do you want to add "end" to the list or not? Did you know `while(condition) {..do stuff..}` is also possible?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that I have to. I just need to be able to type end and that should stop adding elements.

Comment: Well, i assume you don't... who writes "end" at the end of each list? "end" is probably a stop command. And is `listOfItems` necessary? Or should the list just be expanded until the user enters "end"?

Comment: It is actually required to have the listOfItems, as mentioned the user can say that he wants to add 1000 items into the vector but if he decides not to add that many, he can just type 'end'.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the value 'END' before actually inserting otherwise you will have that value inside your h shopping list (you could just pop the last item but nah).

```
//Check if v is not END before actually inserting the element
for(std::string v; shoppingList.size() < listOfItems 
                   && std::cin >> v && v != "END" && v != "end";) {
  //Move it since you won't use v anymore
  shoppingList.push_back(std::move(v));
}
```

Comment: Totally agree, just wasn't sure about adding it to this

Answer (score 0):

```
string value;
cin >> value;
for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems && value != "END" && value != "end"; i++) {
    shoppingList.push_back(value);  // add new value to vector 
    cin >> value;
}
```

This will do what you want. It...reads a value in from the user. Checks if that value is "end" or "END" and that we still don't have enough items. It adds what they entered to the shopping list (now that we've determined it's good). It reads another item and does it all again.

Comment: DRY=don't repeat yourself ;P

Comment: @JHB sorry, I didn't get that, could you say it again? :P are you talking about the double `cin` though?

Comment: almost but it is not exactly what I'm looking for, yes, it allows me to add elements and stop the program by typing 'end'. Yet, when I declare I want to add just 3 elements, it should allow me to do just that, this method even If i just declare 6 elements to be added; it keeps asking me for more than 6 values..

Comment: @Kir how do "declare [you] want to add just 3 elements?" My assumption is the number of elements you want is stored in the integer, `listOfItems`. Where is it actually?

Comment: @scohe001 check my updated question. listOfItems is just a single int variable that I instantiated to 0; it will be change after the user submits an integer.

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce that @Kirasiris. Looks like this code will respect the number in `listOfItems`:  https://ideone.com/ruWlze

Comment: can you make an answer? Got it working with that example!. That one accepts the typing of end if user submits it and/or it let me add the exact amount of elements specified in the listOfItems variable.

Comment: I just copied the exact code in my answer into that @Kirasiris...what else do you want me to add to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to accept input in your while loop:

```
do {
    string value;
    cin >> value;
    shoppingList.push_back(value);  // add new value to vector
} while(value != "end" && value != "END");
```

Otherwise this will run continually. This way, you actually base what you're inserting in the `std::vector` on user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
string value;
int i = 0;
while(cin>>value && i++ != 10 && value != "END" && value != "end")
{
   shoppingList.push_back(value);
}
```

Comment: Won't this add an empty string to the beginning of `shoppingList` every time? (also I want to make it clear that I'm not trying to be accusatory with my repeated commenting on your answer. I mean no offense here. I'm only trying to make sure that your answer is as correct as it can be)

Comment: You can check. -:) It won't

Comment: You're not seeing it output because it's an empty string. [Try this](https://ideone.com/8T1Uxn) that outputs list size and commas in between (ignore the trailing comma at the end that I was too lazy to deal with).

Comment: I thought you were looking for a solution. check the answer now. Added one more way

Comment: The second one looks like it'll work to me. Nice! Might as well do `i++ != listOfItems` though instead of `i != 10`. That way you don't need the `i++` in the loop body, and you conform to OP's question by looking at `listOfItems`. I like that solution! :)

Comment: @scohe001 That optimization is upto you. You can play as you want.